# How to create a covariate × time interaction term in Cox regression?

Tags: survival, interaction, cox-model

In Cox regression, it is sometimes inevitable that the strength of a predictor will vary across time (Singer & Willett). This violates the proportionality assumption, but can be incorporated in the model as an interaction term between the covariate and time (or the log of time).

How does one create this interaction term (by hand)? If the predictor has only one single value per subject (e.g., gender coded as 1 or 0), how can this be multiplied by time – which for each subject, takes on many values (e.g., if time is measured in days, and the study is 100 days long, then $t=\{1,...,100\}$)? Is the predictor value multiplied by the *event time* (e.g., death)?

I've read from some sources that you multiply the covariate value by a *function* of time, but I'm not sure if this is accurate, or how one would do this in a data set by hand.

Comment: I found a resource that shed some light on this.

Comment: It might be helpful for others if you posted a link to that resource here.

Comment: John Fox has companion R code to his book on regression in which he uses time-varying covariates and an interaction with time in a Cox model. The code is a little dense and requires some unpacking but here's a link to the resource:
http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Fox-Companion/cox-regression.txt

Comment: There is a great answer to this question here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112555/what-s-wrong-with-this-way-of-fitting-time-dependent-coefficients-in-a-cox-regre

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @half-pass about the linked post. Further, should be no reason you do this in R or Stata as you can see from the answers in the post @half-pass [links to](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112555/what-s-wrong-with-this-way-of-fitting-time-dependent-coefficients-in-a-cox-regre).

There is also an example in the end of the [Using Time Dependent Covariates and Time Dependent Coefficients in the Cox Model](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf) vignette of the `Survival` package (version 2.41-3) which shows you how to make the expanded data set you ask for.